# How do I make a label count up when iterating through my listView items

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, listview, increment

So I have this listview and I can add items to it through a openfiledialog and then I do File.ReadLine and read through all the lines of the textfile I just selected.

So let's say I selected a textfile with 3 lines in it.

Bob
Cat
Human

then what it does is it adds the items to the listview.

Now for every item it adds I want to increment the label (add from 0 > 3).

```
private void btnAddItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Names|*.txt";
            if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string[] recipients = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);

                foreach(string name in recipients)
                {

                    lvRecipient.Items.Add(name);
                    //increment the number of items in the list
                    foreach(int item in lvRecipient.Items)
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        i++;
                        lbCount.Text = i.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I tried that but got an error as soon as I ran it, I was pretty sure it wouldnt work because there is no real locig behind it, how do I make my label increment from 0 > 3 (or how ever many items there are in the textfile)?

Comment: Move that `int i = 0;` declaration outside those loops.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the question that you asked, it can be done like this:

```
private void btnAddItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Names|*.txt";

    if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] recipients = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);

        foreach(var name in recipients)
        {
            lvRecipient.Items.Add(name);

            lbCount.Text = lvRecipient.Items.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

It would be better to just set the count label after all the items were added, rather then setting it every time a new one is added because the adding operation should be very quick making it unlikely a human would even detect the changing number. This could be done like so:

```
private void btnAddItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Names|*.txt";

    if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] recipients = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);

        foreach(var name in recipients)
        {
            lvRecipient.Items.Add(name);
        }

        lbCount.Text = lvRecipient.Items.Count.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: That works! But it's not counting really, it jumps from 0 > 1000.

Comment: @JonnyKhanas I updated the answer to solve your exact question, and also included what I think may be a better solution.

Comment: It still jumps, even if I put it inside the foreach loop

Comment: @JonnyKhanas yes that is because the add operation is very quick. It likely takes on the order of milliseconds to all the items. If you want to see the number slowly tick up add `Thread.Sleep(1000);` inside the foreach loop, although this is why I recommend only setting the count at the very end- a human wont detect that label changing so fast.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: It "jumps" because you're executing a **blocking loop on the main UI thread**, and it can't update itself until **after** the button handler has completed.  To "fix" it, you'd have to move that code to a background thread and properly Invoke() the updates.  You'd need a large file for this to be noticeable, and it will slow things down...

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Jonny
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAddItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofd.Filter = "Names|*.txt";
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string[] recipients = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);

                    foreach (string name in recipients)
                    {
                        lvRecipient.Items.Add(name);
                        //increment the number of items in the list
                        foreach (var item in lvRecipient.Items)
                        {
                            int i = 0;
                            i++;
                            lbCount.Text = i.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It does work - I tried it. If you just change the "int" to "var" - because the "lvRecipient.Items" is unable to be treated as an integer in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

this could be what you are looking, maybe someone will find it useful, my function is running async though and i had to to invoke the label.

```
delegate void SetTextCallback1(string name);
private void SetTextLabel(string name)
{
    if (this.label1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback1 d = new SetTextCallback1(SetTextLabel);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { name });
    }
    else
    {
        this.label1.Text = name;
    }
}
```

then i used task.run :

```
await Task.Run(() => SetTextLabel(name));
```

and of course the Task.Run line is inside a loop wrapped in an async func.